# VS2010 loading very slow

Tags: visual-studio-2010

My visual studio 2010 has been loading slow lately (takes almost 2 minutes to start up, sometimes hangs even longer).

I've debugged it with devenv /log then pasted the ActivityLog.xml into excel and then calculated the time difference between each logged step.

```
694: Information: VSCommands is up to date [10.3.9.12]                      
695: Information:                                                        
696: Information: Web    : http://vscommands.squaredinfinity.com                
697: Information: Twitter: http://twitter.com/vscommands                    
698: Information: Email  : support@vscommands.com                           
699: Begin export of category 'Environment_CallBrowser' ({50B05A5D-9174-48eb-851A-B1C616A0B43D}) from package 'Visual Studio Environment Package' ({DA9FB551-C724-11D0-AE1F-00A0C90FFFC3}).  3176716 KB of virtual memory currently available.                                  
700: End export of category 'Environment_CallBrowser' ({50B05A5D-9174-48eb-851A-B1C616A0B43D}).  3176716 KB of virtual memory currently available.
```

Supposedly between step 698 and 699 it took 71 seconds and I have no idea why?

Comment: Visual Studio is a big program, what are your computer specs?

Comment: CPU - i7-2600 CPU @ 3.40GHZ
RAM - 8 GB
OS - Win 7 Pro 64bit

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue before - Deleting the associated .suo file will help, since they become a bit bloated over time.  You'll lose bookmarks and preferences, however.

Answer (score 0):

Tools > Options Environment > Add-in/Macros Security -- UNCHECK "Allow Add-in components to load" Tools > Extension Manager Uninstall all you don't need.

Tools > Options > Environment > Uncheck "Automatically adjust visual experience based on client performance" then uncheck "Enable rich client visual experience". Tools > Options > Environment > Startup: At startup = "Show empty environment" Tools > Options > Source Control Set to "None"